# how i can create master report by stimulsoft report from code c#

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

i have two table Patients and PatientStudy in my database that created by code first entity framework.
these tables have a relation with foreign key patient_id in studypatient table.
my code is as below:

```
var patbus = new StiBusinessObjectData("Test", "Patient",Patients.ToArray());
        var studies=new List<PatientStudy>();
        foreach (var patientStudies in Patients.Studies.ToArray())
        {
            studies.AddRange(patientStudies);
        }
        var studySrc = new StiBusinessObjectData("Test", "PatientStudy", studies);
        report.BusinessObjectsStore.Add(studySrc);
        report.BusinessObjectsStore.Add(patbus);
        report.Dictionary.Synchronize();

        var pds = report.Dictionary.DataSources["Patient"];
        var sds = report.Dictionary.DataSources["PatientStudy"];
        StiDataRelation rel = new StiDataRelation("Studies", pds, sds, new string[] { "Id" }, new string[] { "Patient_Id" });

        report.Dictionary.RegRelation(rel);
        report.Dictionary.Relations.Add(rel);
        report.Dictionary.Synchronize();

        report.DesignWithWpf();
```

when i run this code, in stimulsoft design view two business object data (patients and patientstudy) added but the relationship between them do not apply.
i need help
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to add a relation between Business Objects and DataSource.
There should be a structure of business objects or Data Sources.